# Use VB to Convert Excel to PDF and Group by Manager Name

Tags: vba, excel, pdf-generation, excel-2010

I have a working code that I need to update. Currently I have a data sheet with employee information that gets looped through the code below.

Each EmployeeNumber is in a drop down list on the dashboard (this is the range for the loop). The  data, graphs, and pictures that are displayed on the dashboard are what currently prints to the PDF. I am hoping to add the manager name to the data and be able to group my PDFs by manager. It is extremely time consuming to group each employee PDF manually which is what we are currently doing.

Any assistance or recommendations would be greatly appreciated! I was unable to find a thread so far that matched with what I want to do and am desperately seeking a solution. Thank you for reading!

Here is what I have so far (prints each employee PDF and saves it to a folder):

```
Sub PDFexport()

Dim Counter, i As Integer
Dim AOR As String

Sheets("DataSheet").Select
i = 0
Counter = Range("AQ1")

Do While i < Counter

Range("AL1") = Range("AQ4").Offset(i, 0)

AOR = Range("AL1")

i = i + 1
Sheets("dashboard").Select

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\AliceAyers\Documents\WeeklyReport\Week_100814\PDF\" & EmployeeNumber & ".pdf" _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, From:=1, To:=1, OpenAfterPublish:=False


Sheets("DataSheet").Select

Loop







End Sub
```

Comment: What does "group my PDF's by manager" mean in practice?

Comment: Ideally I would like to have the PDFs print out by Manager where each employee would belong to one manager. This means that one Manager would have 15 PDFs that are grouped into one document instead of have 15 separate PDFs print out for each employee. I know how to do this in SSRS but I have never done it in VBA unfortunately. (example: TomSmith.PDF will contain Employee 1, Employee 2 & Employee 15 dashboard printouts where Tom Smith is the manager for each of these employees.)

Comment: I don't think Excel is capable of appending to an existing PDF, so you'd need to create the (e.g.) 15 dashboards, either on a single sheet or on 15 separate sheets, and then save the single sheet (or selected group of 15 sheets) to a PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option supplied by Tim is a good internal way to create one pdf containing all employees for one manager.
I'm geussing the dashboard contain KPI's or similar, It would be easier to just create a manager folder that each report can sit under then use an external tool to merge to PDF if required like pdftk (www.pdflabs.com). PDFtk is also opensource.

```
Sub PDFexport()

Dim Counter, i As Integer
Dim AOR As String

Sheets("DataSheet").Select
i = 0
Counter = Range("AQ1")

Do While i < Counter

Range("AL1") = Range("AQ4").Offset(i, 0)

AOR = Range("AL1")

i = i + 1
Sheets("dashboard").Select

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\AliceAyers\Documents\WeeklyReport\Week_100814\PDF\" & ManagerNumber & "\" & EmployeeNumber & ".pdf" _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, From:=1, To:=1, OpenAfterPublish:=False


Sheets("DataSheet").Select

Loop

MergePDFs

End Sub
```

Once all the PDFs are created in there folders you could leave it there if that is sufficient or run a dos command like this from vb and output all PDFs to the PDF folder level. Lopping around a list of managers creating a merged PDF for each. Sorry for the incomplete below not sure where you have a list of managers.

```
Sub MergePDFs()

Dim doscmd as String

'loop around each manager number
Do

' This sets the PDFtk command 
' Syntax PDFtk [input files] cat output [output file]
Set doscmd = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk\bin\pdftk.exe C:\Users\AliceAyers\Documents\WeeklyReport\Week_100814\PDF\" & ManagerNumber & "\*.pdf cat output C:\Users\AliceAyers\Documents\WeeklyReport\Week_100814\PDF\" & ManagerNumber & ".pdf"

' execute command in dos shell
RetVal = Shell(doscmd)

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Mark. I think I will do what you and Tim suggested.